# Exception when running Azure Cloud Project

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-emulator

I have created an azure cloud project in visual studio.

1) Used the "Convert to Azure" feature.

2) Added a Https endpoint and certificate.

Attempting to run the project with the azure emulator locally "without debug" the emulator hangs. If I run the project with debugging it seems to start but i get the following exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1'     occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

Additional information: Invalid name.

Parameter name: name
```

After the exception sites fails to continue.

I was wondering if anyone has experienced this issue and how they resolved it?

Additional Information:

```
.net 4.5.1 framework.  
IIS: version 7.5
Azure SDK 2.6
```

So looking into the WaIISHost.Log I have found the following exception which keeps being thrown:

```
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00014196:00000001, 2015/07/15     07:45:38.428,ERROR]         Exception:System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDeta    il]: Invalid name.
Parameter name: name (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely     created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.ArgumentException: Invalid name.
Parameter name: name
   at     System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType     resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle,     AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName,     ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity..ctor(Boolean     isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean     isDirectory)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity..ctor(String name,     AccessControlSections includeSections)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections     includeSections)
   at     Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.FileManager.AddAllowAceIte    rative(DirectoryInfo dir, FileSystemRights rights, IdentityReference[]     accounts)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurato...).
```

Comment: I suspect it is something to do with your system.servicemodel configuration....can you post that from the web.config?

Comment: I don't  have any system.servicemodel configuration in my web.config.

Comment: Do you have any unusually long paths in your project folder?

Comment: Hi Spender, the paths aren't very long to be honest. I'm still digging around.

Comment: Well, this question was the only hit I got on this error and it was caused by having node_modules folder in project folder. Node can handle extremely long file paths, but the azure emulator chokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue in the end.

I'll be completely honest, i'm not entirely sure if its due to long path names as suggested by @spender or if its something else. I had a folder on my C drive called Dev:

```
C:\Dev\AzureSolutionExample\Source
```

I basically moved it directly onto the C drive and everything started working.

```
C:\AzureSolutionExample\Source
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had the same problem and it waste my whole day. Finally after search for all similar errors , I found you comment and it worked for me. I just copy the project and paste it to the root of C:

Comment: Shame on Windows 10 that can not handle long names